# ecryptfs: DDev Magento linux quick start setup failing on "file name too long"

Tags: ubuntu, magento, ddev, ecryptfs

Ubuntu details:

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"

I am trying to install magento on my linux machine. I am using ddev quick start for magento .
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#magento-2

I am getting the following error for this command:

> ZipArchive::extractTo(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/90d2dd07/dev/tests/acce
> ptance/tests/_data/adobe-base-image-long-name-image-long-name-image-long-na
> me-image-long-name-image-long-name-image-long-name-image-long-name-image-lo
> ng-name-image-long-name.jpg): Failed to open stream: File name too long

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQrRF.png)

I think it is due to char limitation in linux. Is there any way i can bypass it?
I cant run the command in the root folder, as we cant run ddev with sudo.

Comment: What docker provider are you using?

Comment: If you're trying to use Docker Desktop for Linux, please don't. See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/docker-installation/#linux

Comment: @rfay  I had issues with docker desktop earlier with other CMSs, hence i completely removed it and now use docker cli.

Comment: @rfay output of "docker version"---
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.0
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        98fdcd7
 Built:             Mon May 15 18:48:35 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Comment: Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.0
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       1331b8c
  Built:            Mon May 15 18:48:35 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

Comment: "Docker CLI" just just the client, it's the same no matter what you're using for the engine. The engine you want to be using is docker-ce, sounds like you've got tat. I'm glad you're not trying Docker Desktop for Linux.  Please do a `ddev debug test` and provide a link to the output, perhaps put it on gist.github.com or another pastebin.

Comment: @rfay

https://gist.github.com/Jazyac/950b5cd0c6a56495a49ffb7a5a5fadd0

Comment: I just did a magento2 installation on Ubuntu 20.04 using the instructions at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#magento-2 without any trouble. I suspect you must have an unusual filesystem or are using a network filesystem mount.

Comment: `df -T .` in the project directory should show you running with ext4. `ddev exec df -T /var/www/html` should also show you running ext4 on a standard Ubuntu setup.

Comment: `df -T .` in the project directory should show you running with ext4. `ddev exec df -T /var/www/html` should also show you running ext4 on a standard Ubuntu setup.

Comment: @rfay
https://gist.github.com/Jazyac/62088a44b44b398761db1fb5aa86d24d

Comment: Yes, your filesystem is of type ecryptfs, not standard Ubuntu. You'll find lots and lots of answers by searching https://www.google.com/search?q=ecryptfs+file+name+too+long&oq=ecryptfs+file+name&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30j0i15i22i30l4j0i390i650l3.6151j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: thanks @rfay. atleast now i know what to address.
my home directory is ecryptfs, whereas anything outside of it is still ext4. is there any way to run ddev with root? i get permission denied errors when i try to install magento using ddev outside the home directory.

Comment: @rfay i bypassed the issue by creating a non-root owned directory outside home.thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@rfay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215713/rfay) has pointed out, this was due to my home folder being encrypted using ecryptfs, leading to filename encryption hitting the limit.
As a workaround, I have-

created a separate directory outside of my home directory and set the appropriate permissions to allow ddev to access it. Here's a step-by-step guide:

Create a new directory: Choose a location outside your home directory, for example, /opt/magento.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/magento
```

Set ownership and permissions: Assign ownership of the directory to my user account and set the appropriate permissions.

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /opt/magento
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/magento
```

Then i just used this folder for magento.