# Magento2: 503: No ddev back-end site available

Tags: docker, ubuntu, magento, ddev

I am trying to install magento on my linux machine. I am using ddev quick start for magento . https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#magento-2

I am getting the following error for `ddev launch`:

```
503: No ddev back-end site available.
This is the ddev-router container: There is no back-end webserver at the URL you specified. You may want to use "ddev start" to start the site.
```

I was initially encountreing 404 nginx errors upon launching, after which I ran the following.

```
ddev poweroff 
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
ddev restart
```

The above resolved the 404 error. But now I am seeing the 503.
I have tried the following things from the [troubleshooting](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/) --

1. ddev poweroff
   docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
2. [ddev debug dockercheck](https://gist.github.com/Jazyac/5f0ddae2f2f0498930d1ed8dd6a1e318)
3. [ddev debug test](https://gist.github.com/Jazyac/2447b2fe98a02298771e0cfdb39a943b)
4. Restart Docker
5. Try the simplest possible DDEV project
6. sudo service nginx stop
7. sudo apachectl stop
8. [Method 2: Fix port conflicts by configuring your project to use different ports](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#web-server-ports-already-occupied:%7E:text=Method%202%3A%20Fix%20port%20conflicts%20by%20configuring%20your%20project%20to%20use%20different%20ports)
9. [sudo lsof -i :443 -sTCP:LISTEN](https://gist.github.com/Jazyac/ab403f2133cf57055b2dabe759343a2e)
10. sudo lsof -i :8443 -sTCP:LISTEN (EMPTY)

my .ddev/config.yaml file looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/Jazyac/05be0268a981bea0f690b8d29eec5b91)

I am using docker ce, not docker desktop. I am using ubuntu with the following details--

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"

[Due to issues with filename encryption, the magento folder resides outside the home directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76427607/ecryptfs-ddev-magento-linux-quick-start-setup-failing-on-file-name-too-long)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtJPy.png)

Comment: 503 is almost always a result of having the docroot wrong. Check to see if the docroot in .ddev/config.yaml matches the directory where your index.php is. (You have "pub" I see; is that the correct relative directory, and does it have index.php inside it?

Comment: I see that `ddev debug test` works fine, so the problem is most likely your docroot. Your docroot must be inside the project.

Comment: Try the 127.0.0.1 URL that `ddev start` gives you and see if that one works.  For unusual problems like you have been having I encourage you to come over to Discord, where interactive support is a lot easier. https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rfay. As my config.yaml shows in the description, the docroot is 'pub'. There is indeed an index.php file inside pub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was sorted out in [DDEV Discord](https://discord.com/channels/664580571770388500/1117943570129748028/1117943570129748028)

It wasn't listed here, but you were trying to create a project with the URL `https://245.ddev.site:8443` but you had followed (most of the) steps of the instructions in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#magento-2

The problem you had is that `magento2` and `wordpress` embed the URL inside the database configuration, so you have to use the exact URL you want when setting up magento2.

You used `ddev magento setup:install --base-url='https://ddev-magento2.ddev.site/' --cleanup-database --db-host=db --db-name=db --db-user=db --db-password=db --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-port=9200 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US` (especially `--base-url='https://ddev-magento2.ddev.site/'`) but unfortunately you were creating a project with the URL `https://245.ddev.site:8443`

So you fixed this by changing the setup to `ddev magento setup:install --base-url='https://245.ddev.site:8443/' --cleanup-database --db-host=db --db-name=db --db-user=db --db-password=db --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-port=9200 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US`

Before you did this, whenever you would land on the index.php magento2 would redirect to its canonical URL, `https://ddev-magento2.ddev.site/`... which of course was not configured in DDEV, so you got the `503: No ddev back-end site available`.